# Import module with the same name as a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to import a module like this: `from boo.foo.moo import cls` but I aready have a package named `boo` in my environement.

I've tried `cls = __import__('boo.foo.moo')` and also `cls = importlib.import_module('boo.foo.moo')` but none of them works. I have a doubt on my syntax but not sure.

Thanks,

Comment: `from boo.foo.moo import cls as bls`
Use import **as**

Comment: still the same error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boo'

Comment: try checking this out  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/